# ArangoDB Graph Creation API

Tags: arangodb

Could someone tell me why the edge collection in the HTTP API takes a list of froms and tos?

The JSON to create a new graph is like so:

```
{ 
  "name" : "myGraph", 
  "edgeDefinitions" : [ 
    { 
      "collection" : "edges", 
      "from" : [ 
        "startVertices" 
      ], 
      "to" : [ 
        "endVertices" 
      ] 
    } 
  ] 
}
```

This leads me to believe that the system can have multiple edgeDefinitions and that each edgeDefinition can have multiple from and to entries. I don't understand the multiple from and to per definition. I get having multiple edge definitions.

Here's the documentation: [ArangoDB Graph Docs](https://docs.arangodb.com/HttpGharial/Management.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A graph in ArangoDB can be used for storing either homogeneous relationships or heterogeneous relationships. If all relations are homogeneous and are stored in the same edge collection, a single edge definition is sufficient.

An edge definition contains the name of the edge collection which stores the relationships (attribute `collection`) as well as the names of the vertex collections that are allowed to store relations in the edge collection (attributes `from` and `to`).

The following example defines a graph with a single edge definition, with connections allowed only between vertex collections `users` and `users`. The relationships are stored in an edge collection named `knows`:

```
  "edgeDefinitions" : [
     {
        "collection" : "knows",
        "from" : [
           "users"
        ],
        "to" : [
           "users"
        ]
     }
  ]
```

Multiple edge definitions can be declared for storing different types of relations in a single graph with multiple edge collections, e.g.:

```
  "edgeDefinitions" : [
     {
        "collection" : "knows",
        "from" : [
           "users"
        ],
        "to" : [
           "users"
        ]
     },
     {
        "collection" : "buys",
        "from" : [
           "users"
        ],
        "to" : [
           "products"
        ]
     }
  ]
```

Note that the it would also be possible to use a single edge definition here and storing all relationships in a single edge collection (now named `connections`). Note that there are still different vertex collections (`users` and `products`) and some restrictions for how they can be connected:

```
  "edgeDefinitions" : [
     {
        "collection" : "connections",
        "from" : [
           "users"
        ],
        "to" : [
           "users",
           "products"
        ]
     }
  ]
```